# web scraping contat list selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How can i loop through contacts in group in Discord using selenium in Python?
I tried this code, and i have this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Problem is scroller and contacts are constantly updating... 
I tried this code:

```
while True:
    num=0
    try:
        users_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.memberOnline-1CIh-0.member-3W1lQa")

        for user in users_list:
            num+=1
            user.click()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",user)
            print('User number {}'.format(num))
    except StaleElementReferenceException and ElementClickInterceptedException:
            print('bad')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight",users_list)
```

Comment: Confirm one thing, did you call `click()` in loop?, If did, please update your code with that part.

Comment: Yes i did use click in loop... i updated code...

Comment: @mr.M Hey, did you found the solution? I would like to see your code and I wanna help you because this project is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

From your given code, you only scroll element, so the reason of `Stale` exception is you not wait page load complete, or at least not wait the contacts not load complete.

For debug purpose, you can simple add a long sleep before the loop, like `sleep(15)`,  and replace to explicit wait if production code, like

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
```

Detail of **Explicit Wait** at [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

If you call `click()` in loop, you need to find the elements again in loop:

```
while True:
    num=0
    try:
        time.sleep(15)
        users_list = driver
            .find_elements_by_css_selector("div.memberOnline-1CIh-0.member-3W1lQa")

        length = len(users_list)

        for num in range(0, length):
            user = users_list[num]
            user.click()
            time.sleep(15)

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",user)
            print('User number {}'.format(num+1))

            // because the above `click` make page happen changes
            // so selenium will treat it as a new page, 
            // those element reference found on `old` page, can not work on `new` page
            // you need to find elements belongs to `old` page again on `new` page
            // find users_list again from `new` page

            users_list = driver
                .find_elements_by_css_selector("div.memberOnline-1CIh-0.member-3W1lQa")

    except StaleElementReferenceException and ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print('bad')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight",
          users_list)
```

Comment: how can i execute click on element now?

Comment: Forgot one code place: `user.click()`, had updated code.

Comment: Y i did that but i get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <div class="memberOnline-1CIh-0 member-3W1lQa"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: I add `sleep(15)`  after `click()` to wait page load triggered by `click()`